# How do I make the NoSuchElementException not show up and replace it with my own error message

Tags: java

So what I am supposed to do it have this code search through the file names.txt (contains about a thousand baby names and their rankings from 1900 to now) for the name that             I type in and have the program print out the name and the rankings. 
   If the name does not exist in the file, it is supposed to print out something like "name not found" or whatever. 
   My problem is that it either prints out 'name not found' about 2k times before it finds the name, or it jsut prints out 'name not found' for every year until I get to the last name and it realizes it's not there. It then prints out the cpu generated error.
   I also am not supposed to have the error just be the computer generated error. 
Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class BabyNames {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
        String findNameOriginal = " ";
        String findName = " ";
        int space = 0;
        int rank = 0;
        int year = 1900;
        System.out.println("This program graphs the popularity of a name in 11 decades' worth of statistics recorded since the year 1900.");
        System.out.print("Type a name: ");
        String name = input.next();
        System.out.println("\nPopularity ranking of name \"" + name + "\"");

        while (!findName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            findNameOriginal = reader.nextLine();
            Scanner nameLine = new Scanner(findNameOriginal);
            space = findNameOriginal.indexOf(" ");
            findName = nameLine.next();
            for (year = 1900; year <= 2000; year += 10) {
                rank = nameLine.nextInt();
                if (findName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    System.out.println(year + ": " + rank);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Name not found");

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

(not sure if this link to the names and data will work)
http://fcps.blackboard.com/@@/3773575E3802F997E96CECF10E46CA25/courses/1/030-1-348-31840002-1314-YR/content/_27024448_1/names.txt

Comment: @RyanM FYI, it is considered OK to [ask and answer homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812), so long as is it clear it is homework and the answers are helpful, not just doing the assignment for the person.

Comment: Edited based on @mbroshi's input: Here are some hints: 1) if you don't want want it to print out "Name not found" every time, then think about what your for loop is doing and what happens in the block of the for loop on each iteration. 2) Think about the condition in your while loop; a while loop will execute forever until the condition is no longer true. Do you want to really want to continue to loop until the name is found? What happens when you're out of names in the file?

Comment: I have no clue what other loop to use in this instance :( we are restricted from using arrays as well and the only loop that i could make the code work so far is the while loop

Comment: The loop is not the issue; a `while` loop works just fine for what you're trying to do.  Remember what it does: executes the loop as long as the condition is `true` or until you `break` out of it.  You're predicating your `while` loop on `findName` not being found.  When you reach the end of the list of names, your condition is still `true`, i.e. `findName` hasn't been found, so the `while` loop executes again, calling `reader.nextLine()` and so forth, even though you're out of lines.  @Belgian pointed out the right answer: condition the while loop on `reader.nextLine() != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a boolean that tracks whether the name was found:

```
 boolean found=false;
    while ((findNameOriginal = reader.nextLine()) != null)
      {
         Scanner nameLine = new Scanner(findNameOriginal);
         space = findNameOriginal.indexOf(" ");
         findName = nameLine.next();            
         for (year = 1900; year <= 2000; year += 10)
         {
            rank = nameLine.nextInt();        
            if (findName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            {
               System.out.println(year + ": " + rank);
               found=true;
            }


         }

      }  
if(!found) System.out.println("Name not found");
```

Comment: it still made the name not found print out many times then still got the cpu error upon completion of scanning the file

Comment: Look at the while loop condition though, it needs to be based on the line being null.

Comment: sorry if this is aggravating to you, I kinda still suck, but anyway how do i make line equal to null when I am using line as a string?  just gives me error of incompatible types

Comment: No problem, not aggravating at all. It will be null if the reader doesn't find a string. `reader.nextLine()` returns null if it cannot find a "next line".

Answer (score 0):

Check your `while` condition what will be...

```
while (!name.trim().equals(null)) {
    try{
    //your code
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
  }
```